# How can I open a hidden file in Text Wrangler?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a .bash_profile file in my Home folder but it is hidden. How can I open it with Text Wrangler (or any other text editor?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the terminal :

```
open ~/path/to/.YourHiddenFile -a /Application/YourApplication.app
```

The hidden file are hidden by adding a dot in the beginning of the file name.

Or with the good old GUI method :

1. Launch the application you wish to use to edit or view the hidden
   file.
2. Select ‘Open’ from the application’s File menu.
3. An Open Dialog box will display.
4. With the dialog box as the front-most window (you can click once in
   the dialog box to make sure it’s in front), press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
5. The dialog box now will display any hidden files or folders within
   its list items.
6. You can toggle between the hidden files and folders being displayed
   by pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> again.

Comment: I do not have the  on my MBA keyboard ? where is it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃, it's right next to 

Comment: long ago keyboards had an apple on the command key... There was even a filled in apple on one and an open apple on the other so they could tell people to use one or the other... Not sure if they actually did different things though.